# Wiring low voltage doorbell wire through exterior wall and studs

Tags: electrical, wiring, low-voltage, doorbell

I currently have a battery powered doorbell that I would like to replace with a hardwired doorbell. Problem is, my house is not wired for a doorbell.

My solution is to replace the outlet in the picture, with one of these doorbell transformers: [Broan-NuTone C915 Doorbell Transformer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001PO2BK2)

Now, the only issue I have is running some doorbell wire a few feet through an exterior wall to this outlet that will be replaced by the transformer.

My idea is to use a long bit, like this: [5/16" x 36" Snakebit wiring drill bit](http://www.snakebitdrill.com/516extralonghighspeedsteelsnakebit.aspx) and drill straight through the exterior trim where I want the wire to come out, through a couple studs in the exterior wall and to the stud bay where the outlet box is, then pull the wire down to the box. All while just drilling once, hopefully eliminating opening up the drywall in each stud bay. I am hoping to only have a hole in the stud bay where I need to pull the wire down.

Is this the best way to do this? Are there any issues that I might not be seeing? Is there a better way?

[image: Wiring Plan]

[image: Another angle. Don't want to go through tiny part of wall door is on]

[image: Doorbell location]

Comment: What's below?  Is there a crawl space or basement?

Comment: @jay613 - A finished basement is below

Comment: Do not eliminate the receptacle it is required by code a doorbell is not. It is more common to have the transformer in the attic or a furnace room. Jack has it correct for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plan has a good chance of succeeding as I have done similar work and was successful. I would suggest adding a new junction box, old work box, close to your existing outlet. You can't just go around eliminating outlets because you need the box. Code requires where you need to put them. Just add a new box, pigtail the feed from the existing outlet to the new box and install your transformer. Getting your new wire down there before installing the new box will make it easier.

Comment: True, I didn't think of this. I will add a new box being fed by the old one

Answer (score 0):

Drop the wire in the outside wall behind the bell.  Either in the stud bay or maybe if there is space behind the wood trim do it there.   Then drill from outside, at the level of the box, straight into a side punch out of the box.  The only visible patch is to the wood.  Much easier to patch up white painted wood at shin level than to patch the wall where you're planning.

Comment: I'm not sure I can drop the wire from where the doorbell will be, because it is a corner wall with a door. Wouldn't there be a couple studs there and not an empty bay? I assume the face of a 2x4 would be preventing me from doing this.

Comment: I doubt it's a solid wall of studs.  Try a stud finder on the inside wall.

Comment: true, I mean the wall that the doorbell is going on, the doorbell will be on the edge (so face) of a 2x4, and I think usually they run those two deep in the corners.